# R Import Multiple Tables from database using sqlQuery

Tags: r

I know how to import a table from the database, it works; but what if I have 6 tables, is there a better way to import from 6 different tables and create 6 different data.frames ?

Notes <- sqlQuery(dbConnection, "
                      SELECT *
                      FROM
                      Table1")

??

Comment: *is there a better way to import*? Better way from what? Calling SQL commands from a database?

Comment: do you not know how to read ? in there a better way to import more than one table with the sqlQuery ? without repeating that statement 6 times ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider an `lapply` call across a list of tables:

```
tableList <- c("Table1","Table2","Table3","Table4","Table5","Table6")

# BUILD LIST OF DFS FROM QUERIES
dfList <- lapply(tableList, function(t) sqlQuery(dbConnection, paste0("SELECT * FROM ",  t))

# NAME EACH ELEMENT TO CORRESPONDIND TABLE NAME
dfList <- setNames(dfList, tableList)
```

And then if you want separate dataframes use `list2env` but you can always work directly from *dfList* to avoid many objects in global environment:

```
list2env(dfList, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Great, thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!!!! Parfait

Comment: dfList <- lapply(tableListBase, function(t) fetch(dbSendQuery(con, paste0("SELECT * FROM ",  t))))